# Is there a way to use a microsoft sql select statement that allows me to use the where clause to find ●●●●●●●●?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am going through our sql data and at times ●●●●●●●● appears in the data in particular fields.  I know how its getting there but I do not know how to search for it.

```
USE [Kinetics_model2]
GO

SELECT [Id]
      ,[lastPort]
      ,[nextPort]
FROM [dbo].[Observation]
WHERE lastPort = '●●●●●●●●'
```

returns no rows.  When I exclude where lastPort = '●●●●●●●●'

| Id | lastPort | nextPort |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10082 | Moerdijk, NL | Terneuzen |
| 10083 | Shanghai, CN | WEN ZHOU |
| 10084 | Onomichi-Itozaki, JP | Samarinda, ID |
| 10085 | Guangzhou, CN | Unknown Port |
| 10086 | Yizheng, CN | NANGJING |
| 10087 | Qinhuangdao, CN | Unknown Port |
| 10088 | ●●●●●●●● | MUMBAI |

returns

Comment: use `where lastPort = N'●●●●●●●●'` - the `●` character probably doesn't exist in the code page of your default collation

Comment: @JonasMetzler the clause `lastPort = '●●●●●●●●'` is very likely to to be treated as `lastPort = '????????'`, and `'????????'` and `N'●●●●●●●●'` are *not* equal, hence why the row is not returned.